# AFNetworking and Token from Django JWT

Tags: python, django, afnetworking, jwt

I have used AFNetworking and I have connected to Django api before.

Now problem is I am trying about token authentication in Django.

http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/

I have tried these in terminal and it is okay.

```
$ curl -X POST -d "username=admin&password=abc123" http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/

$ curl -H "Authorization: JWT <your_token>" http://localhost:8000/protected-url/
```

I can now get token from AFNetworking too. How can I assign that token in my AFNetworking? I am not quite familiar with curl and AFNetworking.

I tried like this in AFNetworking and it is not okay.

```
self.manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SERVER_PREFIX]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.manager.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:method URLString:urlStr parameters:parameters error:&error];

[request setValue:@"Authorization: JWT" forHTTPHeaderField:token];
```

How shall I do?

Answer (score 1):

I got it now. Based on curl command, I need to write like this.

```
NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"token"];

if (token) {
    token = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", @"JWT", token];
    [self.manager.requestSerializer setValue:token forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
}
```